# tablediff tool takes very long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, compare

I'm using tablediff.exe tool to compare two tables for differences and generate a change script on a remote SQL Server but it takes a very very long time to execute(after more than 1.5hour I gave up). tablediff.exe is running on my local machine, but the database is on another server(these are the requirements - I can't do anything about it)

I've profiled the SQL Server and it seems to execute the queries strangely slower then I expected.

The tables have about 2 million records, but when I executed this on my local machine it look a lot less(about 2-3 minutes).

I'm trying to find out what the reasons for this might be and if there's any way to speed this up?

Comment: Could it be that there are too many differences between the two tables and that's why it takes so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tablediff.exe get all data from remote server and compare locally. The long time is time of upload/download  of 2 millions rows.

Make specific query and execute in remote server. Examples:
equals rows

```
SELECT * FROM bd1.schema1.table1
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM bd2.schema2.table2
```

rows in bd1.schema1.table1 and not in bd2.schema2.table2

```
SELECT * FROM bd1.schema1.table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM bd2.schema2.table2
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I've thought about making something like this as a different solution to tablediff, like a stored procedure that executes at some period of time. But how do I generate difference scripts then, I need this functionality also?